# How to share scope context when using multibus with masstransit

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I'm trying to create filters to fill in the correlationId in the consumers and add this correlationId in the sending messages.

But, I believe, because it is multibus the context is different between the 2 configured bus, is there any way to make this work.

Below is an example of one of the filters:

```
public class CorrelationSendFilter<T> :
    IFilter<SendContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    private CorrelationContext _correlationContext;

    public CorrelationSendFilter(CorrelationContext correlationContext) { _correlationContext = correlationContext; }

    public async Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
    {
        context.CorrelationId = _correlationContext.GetOrNewCorrelationId();

        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
}
```

CorrelationContext is defined with scoped in DI

Versions and packages in use:

```
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="7.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="7.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="7.3.1" />
```

Comment: The ability to copy context from a message consumed on one bus being sent to another bus is on the roadmap with no ETA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a consumer on the default bus, and you want to be able to use a scoped interface from another bus (such as `ISecondBus`), you can use the scoped bus context provider on the constructor as shown:

```cs
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.DependencyInjection; // needed for Bind

class FirstMessageConsumer :
    IConsumer<FirstMessage>
{
    readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public FirstMessageConsumer(IScopedBusContextProvider<ISecondBus> contextProvider)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = contextProvider.Context.PublishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<FirstMessage> context)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new PingMessage());
    }
}
```

This should copy the `ConversationId` from the consumed message to the published message, along with any headers. Due to MassTransit's identifier approach, the consumed message's `CorrelationId` would be copied to the `InitiatorId` of the published message. The same should work for `ISendEndpointProvider` if `Send` is required.

Comment: Hi @Chris Patterson thanks for the feedback.


I couldn't find IScopedBusContextProvider and also not an additional MassTransit.DependencyInjection package in nuget.


Another question, would it be possible to use IScopedBusContextProvider, to get the correlationId by the context, inside a filter?

Comment: Then you're likely using an outdated version of MassTransit.